# Handel save as from iframe

Tags: html, iframe, django-templates, screenshot

I have a Django template in which I want to open a web page
(https://ft-graphics.fussballtraining.com/) as an Iframe
this is my template:

```
    {% block tacktic %}
<div id="iframe_div">
    <iframe src="https://ft-graphics.fussballtraining.com/" width="100%" height="100%"
            style="border: none">
    </iframe>
</div>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 1%; ">
    {% if request.sessios.error %}
        <div class="alert-danger">
            {{ request.session.error }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'save' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="created_by" value="{{ user }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="created_at" value="{% now "Y-m-d h:i:s" %}">
        <div class="form-row" style="padding-left: 3%;">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label>
                    <input class="texting textInput form-control" id="comment" name="comment"
                           type="text"
                           placeholder="{% trans 'comment_placeholder' %}" required>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                {{ tactic.image | as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class=" col-md-2">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary rounded" value="{% trans 'save_image' %}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>{% endblock %}
```

I want to know if there is any way to handle save as request from Iframe an store it in the image filed so I can save the image without uploading it one more time

Answer (score 0):

I have found a tricky solution,

```js
    
  $(document).ready(function () {
   
    let image_file = "";
    let can = document.createElement("canvas");
    can.id = "screenShoot";
    can.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute;");
    can.setAttribute("hidden", "");
    let take_screen_shoot = async () => {
        let find_can = document.getElementById("screenShoot")
        if (find_can == null)
            document.getElementById("form_container").appendChild(can);
        let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({displaySurface: 'active-window'});
        let track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
        let image = new ImageCapture(track);
        let bitmap = await image.grabFrame();
        track.stop();
        let canvas = document.getElementById("screenShoot");
        canvas.width = bitmap.width;
        canvas.height = bitmap.height;
        let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        //drawImage(video, domX, domY, domWidth, domHeight, 0, 0, domWidth, domHeight);
        context.drawImage(bitmap,
            50, 50,  // Start at pixels from the left and the top of the image (crop),
            bitmap.width - 100, bitmap.height - 200,   // Get a  (w * h) area from the source image (crop),
            0, 0,
            bitmap.width, bitmap.height //scaling
        );
        let img = canvas.toDataURL();
        let result = await fetch(img);
        let buffer = await result.arrayBuffer();
        let name = document.getElementsByName("created_by").item(0).value;
        let date = document.getElementsByName("created_at").item(0).value;
        /*let img_file = canvas.toDataURL().replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
        downloadBase64File("image/png;base64", img_file, name + "_" + date);*/
        image_file = new File([buffer], name + "_" + date + ".png", {type: 'image/png'});
    };
    $("#plan_form").submit(function (event) {
        // Prevent the default form submit
        event.preventDefault();
        let form = this;
        let formData = new FormData(form);
        take_screen_shoot().then(function () {
            formData.append('image', image_file)
            $.ajax({
                url: form.action,
                type: form.method,
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                success: [function (response) {
                    form.reset();
                    createConfirmDiv(response['message']);
                }],
                error: [function (response) {
                    alert("failed to submit form!");
                }]
            });
        })
    });
});

function createConfirmDiv(message) {
    $("#form_container")
        .append('<div id="alert" class="alert alert-success " role="alert" style="width: fit-content">' + message + '</div>' +
            '<script type="text/javascript">'
            + 'setTimeout(function () {' + '$("#alert").alert("close");' + '}, 3000);' + '</script>')
}
```